# SabreDAV Client create calendar object

Tags: php, caldav, sabredav

I'm try to add an calendar opject into my SabreDAV server. From an existing client (like iOS or iCalendar on OSX) this works great. But when trying to add a new calendar object I get the following error:

> Sabre\CalDAV\Exception\InvalidComponentType
>     iCalendar objects must at least have a component of type

vcal->serialize has the following output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Sabre//Sabre VObject 4.1.2//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:sabre-vobject-62abb501-ad16-459b-8891-31e33cf5e9f2
DTSTAMP:20180922T111429Z
SUMMARY:hey
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20180922T095000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:32000922T153800
ATTENDEE:mailto:calendar@domain.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The code I use for adding a request:

```php
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$begin = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime ."-30 minutes")), new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$end = new \DateTime(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime))), new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

require('vendor/sabre/autoload.php');
$vcal = new \Sabre\VObject\Component\VCalendar();
$vevent = $vcal->add('VEVENT');

$vevent->add('SUMMARY', 'hey');
$vevent->add('DTSTART', $begin);
$vevent->add('DTEND', $end);

$vevent->add('ATTENDEE', 'mailto:calendar@domain.com');

$this->davClient->request('PUT', 'calendars/admin/Rekenen/'.uniqid().'.ics', $vcal->serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the root cause of the issue but your DTSTART and DTEND do reference a timezone with TZID "Europe/Amsterdam" while your iCalendar stream does not include a corresponding VTIMEZONE component that would give the definition of this timezone.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
...
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Some servers do accept such reference without definition while some others do not.